# Kafka Connect JDBC sink connector issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Getting below error while running JDBC sink connector

```
[2020-01-08 15:05:39,271] ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' was not found. Returning: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@6f2cfcc2 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:165)
[2020-01-08 15:05:39,272] INFO Finished creating connector test-sink (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:273)
[2020-01-08 15:05:39,273] ERROR Plugin class loader for connector: 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector' was not found. Returning: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader@6f2cfcc2 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:165)
[2020-01-08 15:05:39,273] INFO SinkConnectorConfig values:
```

I have set plugin path properly as per given in the documentation.

Comment: Which version are you running? How have you installed Confluent Platform?

Comment: kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.2.jar

Comment: Please show your plugin path config and the files within that directory

Comment: I have created a new folder for the plugin as   kafka_2.11-2.4.0/plugin and inside that, I have kept the Kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.2.jar. The same path is given in the standalone config for the plugin.path. When I am starting my Kafka connect in standalone, initially its showing added plugin but getting above error when loading class

Comment: Have u installed Confluent Platform?

Comment: @FatemaSagar I am using kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.2.jar

Comment: @rsarda Can you confirm that the sink connector is not actually working? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9186 suggests that this may not be a fatal error. You could also try running this using Confluent Platform (which ships with the JDBC connector installed), and then revert to plain Apache Kafka once you have it working successfully there

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with you and just solved it. The point here is you should not copy the connector jar file to the kafka libs directory. You should set the CLASSPATH during running the command like this:

```
env CLASSPATH=./* connect-standalone.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/connect-standalone.properties config/quickstart-couchbase-source.properties
```

or set the plugin.path in the worker .properties file.

```
plugin.path=/path_to_the_plugin_jar_file
```

Hope this help.